# Print only desired columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I would like to just display desired columns when doing print.  Raw data looks like this.

> ['* 10       6cb2.aeee.0db7    dynamic   300        F    F  Po11']

I want **"10"**, "**6cb2.aeee.0db7**", and "**Po11**" to print.

```
with open('c:/sw_mac_addr/test.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: What is wrong with `print('{} {} {}'.format(data[0].split()[1], data[0].split()[2], data[0].split()[-1])`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and supply column indices via a list. This works with negatives indices too:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

x = StringIO("""*\t10\t6cb2.aeee.0db7\tdynamic\t300\tF\tF\tPo11""")
cols = [1, 2, -1]

# replace x with open('file.txt', 'r', newline='')
with x as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print(itemgetter(*cols)(row))

('10', '6cb2.aeee.0db7', 'Po11')
```

Comment: Not sure what variable StringIO is supposed to be.

Comment: See my comment: `# replace x with open('file.txt', 'r', newline='')`

Comment: `StringIO` is a convenience function so the code can be demonstrated without saving / loading external files.

Comment: See this, but I know it's wrong.  open('c:/sw_mac_addr/test2.txt', 'r', newline='') = StringIO("""*\tVLAN\tMAC Address\tType\tage\tSecure\tNTFY\tPorts/SWID.SSID.LID""")
cols = [1, 2, 7]
with open('c:/sw_mac_addr/test2.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print(itemgetter(*cols)(row))

Comment: Don't use `StringIO` in your code! As I said, it's there for *convenience* so it works without a file. Where did `open(...) = StringIO(...)` come from? Use `with open('c:/sw_mac_addr/test.txt', newline='') as fin`.

Comment: I get the following using your script.      print(itemgetter(*cols)(row))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: script I'm using:  from io import StringIO
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

x = StringIO("""*\t10\t6cb2.aeee.0db7\tdynamic\t300\tF\tF\tPo11""")
cols = [1, 2, -1]

# replace x with open('file.txt', 'r', newline='')
with open('c:/sw_mac_addr/test.txt', 'r', newline='') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print(itemgetter(*cols)(row))

('10', '6cb2.aeee.0db7', 'Po11')

Comment: I didn't know about itemgetter, nice, thks.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines=open("Practice.txt",'r')

for line in lines.readlines():
    tokens=line.split(" ")
print(tokens[1],tokens[2],tokens[-1])
```